# Проблема с slick слайдером

Tags: html, css, slider-slick.js

Проблема с slick слайдером следующая, в настройках слайдера написано показывать 2 слайда( то есть два блока), а показывает 3.

```
$('.slider__two').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    prevArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-prev slick-arrow'>Назад</button>",
    nextArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-next slick-arrow'>Далее<img src='images/Arrow-purp.svg' alt=''></button>",
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выяснил, что слайдер на самом деле показывает два блока, а третий просто влезает